# LCM algorithm without prime numbers time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What would be worst time complexity for calculating LCM without prime numbers?
My algorithm in C++:

```
int a, b, a2, b2;
cin >> a;
cin >> b;
a2 = a;
b2 = b;

while(a!=b) {
    if(a>b) b+=b2;
    if(b>a) a+=a2;
}
cout << a << " X " << b << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

In the worst case scenario , your LCM can be `a*b` .
So , in this worst case scenario ,  on the way to calculating LCM in your while loop , number of steps to increment `a` to LCM is `(a*b - a)/a` = `b-1` and number of steps to increment `b` to LCM is `(a*b - b)/b` = `a-1`
So your time complexity will be `O(max(a,b))`

Answer (score 2):

LCM(a,b) is a*b/GCD(a,b)

GCD(a,b) can be computed in O(log(a+b)) time with [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) or [the binary GCD algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm),